# Backbarbuttonitem letterpress effect

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios7, letterpress

How can I recreate the letterpress-like effect applied to the backbarbuttonitem in the notes app in ios 7? I tried the following:

```
NSShadow *textShadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
textShadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, -1.0);
textShadow.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
NSAttributedString *attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Back" attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor orangeColor], NSShadowAttributeName : textShadow}];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:attributedTitle style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
```

But it says I can't use NSAttributedString in place of an NSString.

Answer (score 2):

For iOS 5 and above, you can use the `UIAppearance` functionality to change the Text Color, Font, Tint Color etc of multiple UI Components like UITabBar, UIBarButton, etc.

for UIBarButtonItem, check the below two options.

---

### Option1: For ANY UIBarButtonItem:

```
NSDictionary *aButtonAttribute = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [UIColor darkGrayColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
                                [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 1)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset, nil];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:aButtonAttribute forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

---

### Option 2: For UIBarButtonItem of a UINavigationBar ONLY:

```
NSDictionary *aButtonAttribute = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            [UIColor darkGrayColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                            [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
                            [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 1)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset, nil];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil] setTitleTextAttributes:aButtonAttribute forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

---

***NOTE: You can add these lines (either of the 2 options) in the .m file of AppDelegate..***

Comment: Didn't work: `NSDictionary *backBarButtonItemTextAttributes = @{[NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0.0, -1.0)] : UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset, UITextAttributeTextShadowColor : [UIColor blackColor]};
    [self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem setTitleTextAttributes:backBarButtonItemTextAttributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

Comment: the Answer clearly says.. u have to access the Appearance object of a UIBarButton.. so instead of `[self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem setTitleTextAttributes:backBarButtonItemTextAttributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];`, use 
`[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil] setTitleTextAttributes:aButtonAttribute forState: UIControlStateNormal];`

Comment: Still didn't apply the attributes.

Comment: did u try adding those lines in AppDelegate.?

Comment: Also.. the Key-Value u have in the code is wrong. 
You have mentioned: `[NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0.0, -1.0)] : UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset`
.....
but Key is `UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset`
-------
Format is: `@{key: object}`

Comment: Ok that worked but the back arrow graphic doesn't have the shadow applied.

Comment: Shadow of Text or Shadow of the Button Object?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38688/discussion-between-pedroremedios-and-roshit)