# Using multiple styles for string in UIBarButtonItem title

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, nsmutableattributedstring

If want to use an attributed string to format a string in way that the first word has another styling (e.g. font) than the second word. Therefore I thought I can use `NSMutableAttributedString`. Now I have a `UIBarButtonItem`, but here you only can set the title and the text attributes for the title.

I saw an [implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19208670/426227), where a `NSDictionary` is used to have multiple attributes. The drawback of this is that you can only have a formatting for the whole string. I need it for a part of a string.

Is it possible to have multiple styles for the same title string in `UIBarButtonItem`?

Comment: your question is fine one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can init a `UIBarButtonItem` with a custom view. Prepare your attributed string, create a `UILabel`, set its `attributedText` to the one prepared and then init the button with the label.

Something like this :

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 24)];

NSAttributedString *strt = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"text"
    attributes:@{
                 NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor redColor]
                 }];
label.attributedText = strt;

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:label];
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use like

```
NSMutableAttributedString *;label_text = 
[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithAttributedString: yourlabelel.attributedText];
[label_text addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,1)];
[label_text addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value: [UIColor greenColor] range:NSMakeRange(1,2)];
[label_text addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blueColor] range:NSMakeRange(2,3)];

[yourlabelel setAttributedText: label_text];
```

finally appened this label to your `UIBarButtonItem`

*choice -2*

see this [link](http://soulwithmobiletechnology.blogspot.in/2011/06/coretext-tutorial-for-ios-part-1.html)

Comment: NSMakeRange(0,5) -- length of the string/yourLabel.text

Comment: as per your previous question I created the answer is here